# How to set Elixir, Erlang in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, erlang, elixir

I'm unable to run ElixirLS plugin and the developer states there is an issue with the path settings of Elixir and erlang. How to configure the VSCode settings to run Elixir and Erlang?

System: Linux Mint

Erlang path: /home/ales/.local/lib/erlang/21.0

Elixir path: PATH="$HOME/.exenv/bin:$PATH"

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/ales/.local/lib/erlang/21.0/bin:/home/ales/.exenv/shims:/home/ales/.exenv/bin:/home/ales/gems/bin:/home/ales/.exenv/shims:/home/ales/.exenv/bin:/home/ales/bin:/home/ales/.local/bin:/home/ales/.exenv/shims:/home/ales/.exenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/tesla/.local/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/bin:/home/ales/.local/bin:/local/tools/go/bin:/home/ales/.local/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

I use `asdf` for Erlang and Elixir installations and couldn't make Code even recognize they exist in my system (Manjaro Linux)

My workaround is to start a shell -- where `asdf` shims have ran and injected the proper paths -- and just run `code &`. That made it work.

Comment: I had similar problems, I used this and also copied my .tool-versions to my $HOME folder and this worked for me!